# Jquery get row Index

Tags: javascript, jquery

I having some problem regarding

```
value.indexOf
```

I have a field contains '-', and it show me error, i guess is because of '-'

```
console.log(value.indexOf(row.MALPP-PMP02));
```

i try to put single quote in between but still show me error.

Comment: `i try to put single quote in between but still show me error.`.Show us what you tried. Or you tried as like as below answer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you have a minus sign or other problematic characters you can use `[` and `]`.

i.e.

```
console.log( value.indexOf(row["MALPP-PMP02"]) );
```

without this notation, the javascript parser will attempt to look at `row.MALPP` and then subtract the value of `PMP02`. This is clearly not what you intended.